# What is the YUI2 alternative selector for jquery selector "*" (or) YUI Event/Selector Issue

Tags: jquery, yui, yui2

I am very new to YUI or YUI2

Here i have a criteria, when there are 10 image tags in my page ("").
  when i click on any image i need to get it's parent(i.e) **anchor href value**. when i am trying to do this functionality using the the following **YAHOO.util.Event.addListener** or **YAHOO.util.Event.on**, i am able to fire the event only on the **first img tag** and able to get the value of it's parent **anchor href value**, till now it is fine.

Here my **problem is**, **from the second image** event is not at all firing.
**How i am able to fire event for all the images**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With YUI2, you need to add classes to your elements and use stuff like getElementsByClassName:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/dom/getelementsbyclassname.html

With YUI3, you could just use selectors like jQuery.